# Android OpenGL ES 2: Garbage in mipmap when not using ARGB8888

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, mipmaps

My source images are 512x512 jpegs. Device is a Galaxy Tab 2.

When using the code below (decode as 32bit), my mipmaps are generated perfectly:

```
globalBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Config.ARGB_8888);
...
BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();                             
bmpOptions.inBitmap = globalBmp;                            
bmpOptions.inSampleSize = 1;                                                                                                                                    
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileStream, null, bmpOptions);
...
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);        

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);        
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);                                    

GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

[image: Level 2 Mipmap, Perfect]

However, to keep memory usage to a minimum, I would prefer to load the images as 16bit. RGB_565 makes the most sense, since there is no alpha information. I attempt to do that by changing the following lines:

```
globalBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Config.RGB_565);
...
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, bitmap, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 0);
```

Using 565 yields this nasty mipmap at level 1 onwards. Level 0 is still perfect.
[image: RGB565 Level1]

And one last thing. If i move the filter mode lines to after the mipmap generation, the mipmaps dont have the red tinge, but they also don't look right.

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);        

GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, bitmap, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 0);                                  

GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);        
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

[image: weird]

Also, if I use `Config.ARGB_4444` and `GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`, the red tinge becomes yellow, and doesn't look as bad:

[image: ARGB_4444 Level1]

Please! Somebody shed some light on why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is device specific. So I use ARGB8888 always to be safe. Pity, as it would drastically reduce the memory footprint.